# Order Pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to CMS development, I prefer the MVC concept for every job. But just know the client requested to develop a website built in WordPress. Everything is OK but I can't find to order pages in WordPress.

The case is: first I create a home page and then I create other pages, but the problem is every time I add new pages, it will be placed in my first menu.

So I want to move the home pages in first menu.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom menu (with the pages/links you want, and the order you want !). Then you can add that menu to be the new navigation menu (both header, and footer if you want)

References:

[WordPress Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) (here you can find the step by step 'guide')

Comment: Greaaaaattt.. thanks, I think the pages is menus. I think I would consider to be priority WP for every job that I get :).

Comment: I would totally recommend WordPress for every site you have to make (of course, if it fits the needs, not all sites can be made with WordPress). Just a note: you can have all the menus you want, and be as custom as you need.

Comment: I'm learning about wordpress in this week. I'm figuring out if I can easily manipulate the database if I would make a fairly complex application. Is it easy in wordpress to do that? What can I put PHP libraries such as library databases easily?

Comment: It is very easy. You don't need libraries, WordPress already has want you need, you only need to learn about [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **Appearance --> Menus** and then you'll be able to create menus and edit at will. And if you need to create specific menus, see [WP nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) page. There you'll see several code samples, but you'll need something as simple as

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Nav' )); ?>
```